# How to get the discriminator type from repository

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-2.8

I am currently using a single table inheritence for one of my entities in doctrine. The header look like this:

```
/**
 * Flux
 *
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"flux" = "Flux", "news" = "FluxNews", "mission" = "FluxMission", "offer" = "FluxOffer", "survey" = "FluxSurvey", "linkedin" = "FluxLinkedin", "facebook" = "FluxFacebook", "youtube" = "FluxYoutube", "twitter" = "FluxTwitter"})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\FluxRepository")
 */
class Flux
{

    protected $type = "flux";

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /* other fields */

}
```

I am trying to make a function in the flux repository which will get data from all the flux objects. One of the important data I want to gather is the type of the object (the discriminator field), to know what kind of object it is.

In my repository, my select look like something like:

```
$queryBuilder->select('f.id', 'f.type', 'f.createdAt', 'IDENTITY(f.createdBy) as CreatedBy','COUNT(DISTINCT c.id) as allClicks', 'COUNT(DISTINCT IDENTITY(c.clicker)) as clicks', 'f.postUrl')
            ->groupBy('f.id');
```

`f` being the `flux`. If I remove `'f.type'` it works correctly but I need that data.
If I keep the `'f.type'`, I get the following error:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 15 near 'type, f.createdAt,': Error: Class AppBundle\Entity\Flux\Flux has no field or association named type

I guess it is because since type is the discriminator field, it is not in the normal fields. Is there a way for me to acces that data inside the repository?

I can have access in my controller but I'd really like to keep my code clean and do all of the query for this data in the repository.
The only option I have seen so far is to create another field that juste saves the same type but it's really not clean, I wonder if there is a way using doctrine to get the value of this field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html), you can use **INSTANCE OF** to do it.

As you want to use the discriminator values, using the **class metadata** and constructing a **CASE** expression, you can select the value for each instance:

```
$meta = $em->getMetadataFactory()->getMetadataFor(Flux::class);
$discriminatorMap = $meta->discriminatorMap;
$caseQl = '(case';
foreach ($discriminatorMap as $fieldValue => $class) {
    $caseQl .= " when p INSTANCE OF " . $class . " then '" . $fieldValue . "'";
}
$caseQl .= ' else 0 end) as HIDDEN atype';
$qb->addSelect($caseQl);
$qb->having("atype LIKE :type");
$qb->setParameter('type', '%FluxNew%');
```

Note that the field atype is defined as **HIDDEN**, so that it is not returned in the result.

Also for this solution **having** needs to be used, not where(since the atype is a calculated value).

Alternatively, you could use **Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_INCLUDE_META_COLUMNS** to include the foreign key column values in the result:

```
$paginator->getQuery()
->setHint(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_INCLUDE_META_COLUMNS, true)
->setHydrationMode(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

References:

- [how to get discriminator map values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450381/can-i-access-discriminator-field-from-php-in-doctrine2)
- [Calculated column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27503379/use-a-calculated-column-in-a-where-clause)
- [Force 'fetch joined' relations to include IDENTITY of their ManyToOne relations using HYDRATE_ARRAY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54170887/force-fetch-joined-relations-to-include-identity-of-their-manytoone-relations)

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33360211/how-to-select-discriminator-column-in-doctrine-2). But I think this way is really over-complicated.

If I were you I would just overwrite your query. Make it like this:

`$queryBuilder->select(f, COUNT(DISTINCT c.id) as allClicks, COUNT(DISTINCT IDENTITY(c.clicker)) as clicks)->from(Flux f)->groupBy(f.id);`

You will get mixed results, see [docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#result-format)

So, fetch your needed type from `f`.

I hope you got the idea.

Comment: Thank you but I don't see how your query would help in what I'm trying to do, I'd like to eventually be able to search through the type so I would still need to access 'f.type' in the repository. I looked at the link, and it looks like my issue but the answers don't help me. I guess it is no possible way to do this

Comment: @LioraHaydont  My answer resolves query in the question. If you want to use type in Where clause use INSTANCE OF operator in query

Comment: I can't use INSTANCE OF with LIKE in a query. Like I said, I already have ways to access the type after I get the Flux object in my controller but I want to be able to query on it.

Comment: As you wish. If you have to use LIKE in a query => you can change query to UNION with FROM FluxNews and FluxFacebook for example