# SQL count(*) on a select - division

Tags: sql, count

I have this SQL select and I don't know how can I use 'total' to do the division.

```
select count(*) as total
from table
where id = 15/total;
```

I get this error:

> ORA-00904: "TOTAL": invalid identifier

Comment: Please share more details, like the database system you are using

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27503379/use-a-calculated-column-in-a-where-clause help?

Comment: I'm using oracle database. Or how can I use the 'total' in a select such as - select count(*) as total, partialNumber:=15/total as partial
from table
where id = 15;

Comment: Comparing `id` to the result of arithmetic doesn't really make sense to me.  Can you provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to accomplish?

Comment: I want to get the percentages from a group of ages..eg - there are 33% people which have age between 40 and 45, 50% with age between 20-35 etc..  Can't do the division  bcs 'total' is invalid - count(*)*100/total                                                SELECT (select count(*)
 from table
where id=5) as total, count (*)*100/total as Procents
 FROM tabel
group by id;

Answer (score 3):

use a subquery and analytic function

```
select * from
(
select id, count(*) over() as total 
  from table 
) s
where id=15/total
```

UPDATE based on your comment - finding percent for each age group:

```
select age_group, count(*)*100/total as pct
from
(
select   
      case when age between 40 and 45 then 'group_45'           
           when age between 20 and 30 then 'group_30'
             ... add more groups
           else 'other'
      end as age_group, 
      count(*) over() as total
)s
group by age_group
```

Comment: You typed faster than me... Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

jarih is right you can't use an alias like that, your one alternative is:

```
WITH TOTALS AS (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL FROM TABLE
) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE CROSS JOIN TOTALS
WHERE TABLE.ID = 15/TOTAL;
```